# JointTrajectoryPoint time_from_start Question

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a question about the `time_from_start` parameter in the `JointTrajectoryPoint` message...

Does it mean that the `JointTrajectoryPoint` should already be done executing when the `time_from_start` value is reached? Or does it mean that the `JointTrajectoryPoint` should *start* executing once the `time_from_start` value is reached?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372354/jointtrajectorypoint-time_from_start-question/) by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2021-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Does it mean that the JointTrajectoryPoint should already be done executing when the time_from_start value is reached? Or does it mean that the JointTrajectoryPoint should start executing once the time_from_start value is reached?

A `JointTrajectoryPoint` encodes the *state of the system* at the delta-t from the start of the execution of the `JointTrajectory`.

Personally, I don't believe it's possible to "execute a JointTrajectoryPoint", as it's a point, but if you're asking whether the manipulator should have traversed the *trajectory segment* defined by `pt_(n) - pt_(n-1)` at `pt_(n).time_from_start`, then: yes.

In your words:

> the JointTrajectoryPoint should already be done executing when the time_from_start value is reached

---

Edit: it might help if you see `JointTrajectory` not as a series of motion commands (which they aren't), but as a data structure describing a *spline* through the `JointTrajectoryPoint`s.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2021-02-22**:
Thanks! That helps a lot